# Lua math, detect if rectangle is inside the other rectangle

Tags: math, lua, geometry

I'm trying to make a UI system similar to GMOD's vgui library (https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/vgui). In this library you can create an element, then child of that element. The child of a parent element will be clipped by the parent element's size. So if you have a redbox that has a width and height of 100, the the child element's of the redbox CANNOT be drawn outside the redbox and so on.

Comment: what is your actual question? to find out wether one rectangle is within another is trivial maths. what is OUTSIDE_RIGHT and all those other flags? what is your code supposed to do? if you cannot draw the rect outside of the red rect it is sufficient to draw the red rect. or do you need that white outline? it is not clear what you want to know

Comment: @Piglet oh my.. I forgot to include those variables, I'm trying to figure out how much the Red rectangle is inside it's parent rectangle, which I already do that, but I have a feeling my code is a very hacky way of doing it since i have to have like 10 if statements. Ill update my code to include those variables now

Comment: in your question the red rectangle is the parent, now you say it is the child. what is it?

Comment: The Red rectangle in the context of the picture it's a child element to the grey rectangle behind it. But the Red Rectangle can be a parent to another element, when a Parent element has a child, the child's properties (draw_start_x, and draw_start_y) are relative to the parent's drawing position. ```v.INTERNAL_VARS.draw_start_x = Parent.INTERNAL_VARS.draw_start_x + v.x``` ```v.INTERNAL_VARS.draw_start_y = Parent.INTERNAL_VARS.draw_start_y + v.y``` Maybe I should post the full code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local parent_x = Parent.INTERNAL_VARS.draw_start_x
local parent_y = Parent.INTERNAL_VARS.draw_start_y
local parent_width  = Parent._width
local parent_height = Parent._height

v.INTERNAL_VARS.draw_start_x = parent_x + v.x
v.INTERNAL_VARS.draw_start_y = parent_y + v.y

local child_x = v.INTERNAL_VARS.draw_start_x
local child_y = v.INTERNAL_VARS.draw_start_y
local child_width  = v._width
local child_height = v._height

local x = math.max(child_x, parent_x)
local y = math.max(child_y, parent_y)

draw.DrawOutlinedRect(
   x,
   y,
   math.min(child_x + child_width,  parent_x + parent_width ) - x,
   math.min(child_y + child_height, parent_y + parent_height) - y
)
```